# Shell script to find and replace a string in current directory and all the sub directories

Tags: shell, replace, find

Please help me with this script to replace all the string matching "dev" with "prod" in the current directory and all the sub directories.

Thanks
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find -type f | xargs -i sed -i -e "s/dev/prod/g" {}
```

be careful, -i means inplace and no backup.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `find` to find all files in the current directory and sub-directories and then invoke `sed`. The `-i` option to `sed` edits the files in "inplace".

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/dev/prod/g' {} \;
```